# VBA Input Value From Another UserFormB into TextBox From UserFormA

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

I have a userForm (mappingGuide) that allows user to pick a *smartyTag* from a list of more user-friendly names.

I have a second user-form (conditionalBuilder) that I would like to call this userForm upon double-clicking a text field so that a user can lookup which *smartyTag* to apply (in case they don't know).

So logic, is:

1. open conditionalBuilder
2. double-click Field text box
3. mappingGuide opens
4. pick a smartytag from listbox
5. fill smartytag value into field text-box in conditionalBuilder
6. unload mappingGuide

The issue I think I having with completing the requirement is that when I load the forms themselves I cannot find a way to set the text of the fieldName textbox of the loaded *instance* of conditionalBuilder (see last code block below). I've been searching around, but cannot figure it out.

Here is relevant code:

**conditionalBuilder loads from Custom UI ribbon**

```
Sub RunCode(ByVal Control As IRibbonControl)

    Select Case Control.ID

        Case Is = "mapper": LoadMappingGuide
        Case Is = "conditional": LoadConditionalBuilder

    End Select

End Sub

Sub LoadConditionalBuilder()

    Dim conditionalForm As New conditionalBuilder
    conditionalForm.Show False

End Sub
```

**double-click event of fieldName then loads mappingGuide**

```
Private Sub fieldName_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

    Me.hide
    Dim pickField As New mappingGuide
    pickField.Show False

End Sub
```

**smartTag listbox click event then attempts to place selection into fieldName (or selection if form not loaded)**

```
Private Sub smartTagList_Click()

    If smartTagList.ListIndex > -1 And smartTagList.Selected(smartTagList.ListIndex) Then

        Dim smartyTag As String
        smartyTag = smartTagList.List(smartTagList.ListIndex, 2)

        If isUserFormLoaded(conditionalBuilder.Name) Then
            '*** ---> below is my issue how to reference instance of form 
            conditionalBuilder.fieldName.Text = smartyTag
            conditionalBuilder.Show
        Else
            Selection.Range.Text = smartyTag
        End If

    End If

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

If there is a better set-up that would be great to know too. I have the forms separate because there's a couple of levels a user can create tags with.

Comment: better way will be to use properties on form(s).

Comment: Have you tried: `UserForms("TheNameOfUserForm")`?

Comment: @cyboashu - can you please elaborate or draw it out in an answer or provide a link for more information?

Comment: @MaciejLos - Yes. Didn't work.

Comment: I just realized that you can achieve that using single UserForm. You probably may use MultiPage component to show/hide page which contains ListBox with predefined Tags. This seems to be easier than manage 2 UserForms.

Comment: @MaciejLos - it's definitely worth learning how to do this properly (as given in answers below). When you have more than two userforms to control you definitely need to have a good system for displaying/ hiding form and managing data gathered from the forms

Comment: @CallumDA, you're right, that's why i upvoted your and [cyboashu] answer. It's just another idea. ;)

Comment: @MaciejLos - in this i want to say away from `MultiPage` in my UI. For the projects needs I feel this is cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would do it, a bit of overkill but in case of multiple forms it will be beneficial.

Module 1:

```
 Option Explicit

    Sub test()
        frmMaster.Show False
    End Sub
```

Form 1 : frmMaster:

```
Option Explicit
'/ Declare with events
Dim WithEvents frmCh As frmChild

Private Sub TextBox1_DblClick(ByVal cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    handleDoubleClick
End Sub
Sub handleDoubleClick()

    If frmCh Is Nothing Then
        Set frmCh = New frmChild
    End If

    frmCh.Show False

End Sub

'/ Handle the event
Private Sub frmCh_cClicked(cancel As Boolean)
    Me.TextBox1.Text = frmCh.bChecked
End Sub
```

Form 2: frmChild:

```
Option Explicit

Event cClicked(cancel As Boolean)
Private m_bbChecked As Boolean

Public Property Get bChecked() As Boolean
    bChecked = m_bbChecked
End Property

Public Property Let bChecked(ByVal bNewValue As Boolean)
    m_bbChecked = bNewValue
End Property

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Me.bChecked = Me.CheckBox1.Value
    '/ Raise an event when something happens.
    '/ Caller will handle it.
    RaiseEvent cClicked(False)
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks. I'll have to study this. this goes beyond my current level of understanding but I think could be very useful.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a presenter class which controls userform instances and pass values between them. I mocked up something similar to give you an idea.

> **Presenter**. 
>  This is a class module which creates the userforms, controls their scope, and catches the event thrown by the
>   ConditionalBuilder. It makes it super easy to pass values between
>   userforms.
>
> ```
> Private WithEvents CB As ConditionalBuilder
> Private MG As MappingGuide
>
> Public Sub ShowCB()
>     Set CB = New ConditionalBuilder
>     CB.Show vbModal
> End Sub
>
> Private Sub CB_ShowMappingGuide()
>     Set MG = New MappingGuide
>     MG.Show vbModal
>     CB.UpdateTB1 Value:=MG.SmartTag
> End Sub
> ```

**ConditionalBuilder**. 
This has a simple function to update your textbox and also an event which raises actions in the presenter.

```
Public Event ShowMappingGuide()

Public Function UpdateTB1(Value As String)
    TextBox1.Value = Value
End Function

Private Sub TextBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    RaiseEvent ShowMappingGuide
End Sub
```

**MappingGuide**. 
The `Type` and `Property` could be overkill since we just want one value from the mapping guide but it's still good practice.

```
Private Type TView
    Tag As String
End Type
Private this As TView

Public Property Get SmartTag() As String
    SmartTag = this.Tag
End Property

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Tags.List = Array("a", "b", "c")
End Sub

Private Sub Tags_Click()
    this.Tag = Tags.List(Tags.ListIndex, 0)
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

I have one final **Standard Module** which creates the Presenter. This is what you'd hook up to your ribbon.

```
Public Sub ShowProject()
    With New Presenter
        .ShowCB
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Step 1 (double click text field)

[image]

---

Step 2 (selecting "b")

[image]

---

Step 3 (result)

[image]

Comment: this is pretty awesome, too. thank you. i'll have to study this since it's a bit new for me. thanks again ;)

Comment: Happy to help! If you’ve got any questions ask away :)

Comment: The one question I have is that the code for the two forms in your example, still goes into the userform module, correct? And I can use `With Events` in the mappingGuide form as well, correct, because that will be called on it's own as well with certain actions taken depending on user choice.

Comment: Yes it does and yes you can - although if I remember correctly a quirk of VBA is that you can't compile your Presenter with `Private WithEvents MG...` until you have the corresponding `Public Event SomeEvent` in your MappingGuide

Answer (score 1):

I actually solved it by placing the below block inside the `IF` where I check for the form being loaded and I will leave open for better answers, if there are any.

```
    Dim uForm As Object
    For Each uForm In VBA.UserForms
        If uForm.Name = conditionalBuilder.Name Then
            uForm.fieldName.Text = smartyTag
            uForm.Show
        End If
    Next
```